# Replace the second entry of a filtered data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with over 18m rows in the following format:

```
house_id  date_time              value
1000      2010-10-31 00:30:00    0.6
1000      2010-10-31 00:30:00    0.4
1000      2010-10-31 01:00:00    0.5
1001      2010-10-31 00:30:00    0.5
1001      2010-10-31 00:30:00    0.7
1001      2010-10-31 01:00:00    0.9
```

I would like to replace the second row containing `date_time = 2010-10-31 00:30:00` for each of the different `house_id` with `2010-10-31 01:00:00`, but keep the first instance of `2010-10-31 00:30:00` the same.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has requested to replace the second (last) occurrence of *a particular date time value* for each `house_id`.

According to the OP, the has data set has over 18 M rows which makes it worthwhile to consider an *update in place*, i.e., without copying the complete data object.

#### Update only selected rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)   # coerce to data.table in place
address(DF)
DF[DF[date_time == as.POSIXct("2010-10-31 00:30:00"), last(.I), by = house_id]$V1, 
          date_time := as.POSIXct("2010-10-31 01:00:00")][]
address(DF)
```

The rows to be updated are identified by

```
DF[date_time == as.POSIXct("2010-10-31 00:30:00"), last(.I), by = house_id]
```

> ```
>    house_id V1
> 1:     1000  2
> 2:     1001  5
> ```

The calls to `address(DF)` before and after the update operation is to verify that `DF` has been modified without copying.

#### Update during join

As an alternative to updating selected rows, an update during join can be used:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
address(DF)
DF[CJ(unique(house_id), as.POSIXct("2010-10-31 00:30:00")), 
   on = .(house_id = V1, date_time = V2), mult = "last", 
   date_time := as.POSIXct("2010-10-31 01:00:00")][]
address(DF)
```

which returns the same result:

> ```
>    house_id           date_time value
> 1:     1000 2010-10-31 00:30:00   0.6
> 2:     1000 2010-10-31 01:00:00   0.4
> 3:     1000 2010-10-31 01:00:00   0.5
> 4:     1001 2010-10-31 00:30:00   0.5
> 5:     1001 2010-10-31 01:00:00   0.7
> 6:     1001 2010-10-31 01:00:00   0.9
> ```

Here, `CJ()` creates a lookup table consisting of all unique `house_id`s and the date time to replace.

#### Caveat

The wording of the question suggests that there are *always* 2 rows for each `house_id` with date time `as.POSIXct("2010-10-31 00:30:00")`.

This can be verfied by

```
DF[date_time == as.POSIXct("2010-10-31 00:30:00"), .N, by = house_id][N != 2]
```

which should return an empty data.table.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `dplyr`. The idea is to group the data by `house_id`, and then examine if `date_time` is `2010-10-31 00:30:00` and row number is 2 by `ifelse`. If `TRUE`, replace that value to be `2010-10-31 01:00:00`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(house_id) %>%
  mutate(date_time = ifelse(date_time %in% "2010-10-31 00:30:00" &
                              row_number() == 2, "2010-10-31 01:00:00",
                            date_time)) %>%
  ungroup()
dt2
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   house_id           date_time value
#      <int>               <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1000 2010-10-31 00:30:00   0.6
# 2     1000 2010-10-31 01:00:00   0.4
# 3     1000 2010-10-31 01:00:00   0.5
# 4     1001 2010-10-31 00:30:00   0.5
# 5     1001 2010-10-31 01:00:00   0.7
# 6     1001 2010-10-31 01:00:00   0.9
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "house_id  date_time              value
1000      '2010-10-31 00:30:00'    0.6
                 1000      '2010-10-31 00:30:00'    0.4
                 1000      '2010-10-31 01:00:00'    0.5
                 1001      '2010-10-31 00:30:00'    0.5
                 1001      '2010-10-31 00:30:00'    0.7
                 1001      '2010-10-31 01:00:00'    0.9",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: hmm, I guess this requires the first row per group to be 2010-10-31 00:30:00. In other words, it would fail if the first row is different and only the second row is 2010-10-31 00:30:00.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for your comment, but I thought this is what the OP wants. Without `row_number() == 2`, all `2010-10-31 00:30:00` would become `2010-10-31 01:00:00`. Or perhaps I misinterpreted OP's question.

Comment: And my code will work no matter what the values in the first row is.